# Change name that is default in IIS after PORT:80

Tags: c#, odata, webapi

I want to change the name that is default while the project setup runs through the **IIS**.

This is my default name `OData` :

[image]

I want to change it like :

> http://localhost/ODataAPI/

How could I change this?

Comment: Please add more description about your project structure.

Answer (score 1):

- Click on your site/application.
- on the right panel click on basic settings.
- here you can change the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual directory of that name..
Right-Click on your `Project` and select `Properties`, and then you web and then checked Override application root URL and then Change.

Answer (score -1):

in file program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:4000")
                .Build();
    }
```

use for dotnet core